# What is the best way to read 1 million entries from database with minimum latency?

Tags: system-design

Use Case :
I have a use case where our application has to read 1 million entries( 1 entry = 20 bytes) mapped to a single key. Now we want to extract all these entries with minimum latency.

***Problem 1:*** Which database should I use and how should I store the data.

***Problem 2:*** If I decided to use a DB I can go by 2 approaches :

**Approach 1:** Retrieve all data in a single call (query) wouldn’t it will increase the network payload (since 1 million entries have so large data size to retrieve).

**Approach 2:** I can call DB and retrieve data in batches, but it will increase the number of calls, and hence it will increase the total latency of the application.

I want to know which DB should I use and what approach should I use in order to get minimum latency(say about 200 ms)

Comment: Maybe more a https://dba.stackexchange.com/ related question ?

Comment: Ask yourself if you **really** need that million records all at once. Can you page the query? A user certainly cannot see them all at once, so you don't want to retrieve them all at once either.